# Find all JavaScript Instances in HTML Block - For Security

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Essentially I have an application where people can create their own HTML blocks with a user interface. The problem is someone could manually inject JavaScript in the HTML and when someone else opens that document it executes the malicious code.

I need to check for all instances of JavaScript within an block of HTML at the point of saving and throw an error if JS exists. I am using jQuery.

I have:

```
 // "code" is a jQuery Object 
 if(code.find('script').length > 0){...}
```

which works for script tags, but I have to worry about all the HTML attributes like "onmouseover" ect. Is there an easy way to do this I'm just not seeing?

Comment: You're looking for an HTML sanitizer with a whitelist of tags & attributes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization

Comment: Here's a pretty common one for JavaScript https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html

Comment: I noticed most of these are Node packages. Can I use them as a front-end plugin as well or does the server have to process this for security reasons?